# C memory leak, where there is no memory leak? (valgrind)

Tags: c, memory-leaks

valgrind is telling me that a specific line in my code creates a memory leak, but when looking at that line, it does not seem to even be able to create one.

I am working with this pretty simple Linked List struct list.h:

```
typedef struct _linekd_list{
    void* object;
    struct _linked_list* next;
}linked_list;
```

And this is how a list is initialized in list.c:

```
linked_list* newlist(){
    linked_list * list = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    list->next = NULL;  //As a flag, that there is no next element
    list->object = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

My queue works so, that the first object of the first linked_list is always NULL, the first object is stored in the next linked_list.

Now here is where the memory leak occurs:

```
int list_add(void* new_object, linked_list* list){
        while(list->next != NULL) {  //First go to the end of the queue
            list = list->next;
        }
        list->next = malloc(sizeof(linked_list)); //Vangrind says there is a leak
        list->next->next = NULL; //Set the next list-object to NULL (acts like a flag)
        list->next->object = new_object; //And now store the pointer of the actual object
        if(list->next->object == new_object) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what valgrind tells me:

```
==33369== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==33369==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==33369==    by 0x402219: list_add (list.c:11)
==33369==    by 0x4012D0: main (test_list.c:38)
==33369==
```

Here is the function that recursively frees the list (no memory leak detected):

```
void free_list(linked_list* list){
    if(list->next != NULL) {
        free_list(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the code that (at least you think) frees the memory to avoid memory leak.

Comment: I forgot to take out the extra return 0 statement at the end, my bad

Comment: @Toast What is queue_object? Why is there in sizeof used queue_object list->next = malloc(sizeof(queue_object));?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I changed some variable names without compiling it, my bad. It should be sizeof(linked_list).

Comment: I don't understand what `if(list->next->object == new_object)` is supposed to be doing. That will always be true since you just assigned such that that will be the case.

Comment: @ThomasJager It doesn't really have a use, I just wanted to make sure that everything is working correctly because I still have no idea where that leak is coming from

Comment: @Toast That won't really tell you if something's going wrong. If you have any optimizations turned on, that whole statement is likely completely removed and replaced with `return 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't free the last node in the list.

`free_list` does nothing if `list->next` is `NULL`. But you don't want to do nothing. You want to not recurse, but you still need to free the node. So move the call to `free` out of the conditional, or change the test to check whether `list` itself is `NULL`

Comment: Thank you so much! I even had that line in but deleted it because of a double free error (I originally had no if statement which would mean that every node gets freed two times). Now it works!!

Comment: But why did valgrind talk about a completely other line in a completely other function? Now it doesn't detect any leaks anymore.

Comment: Valgrind tells you where the memory was malloc'd. It cannot tell you where the memory was not freed.